# hive query for selecting top 10 of each category

Tags: hive

I have a hive table with fields similar to :

Seller,catgid,subcatgid,prodid,productdetail1,productdetail2....

Now, I want to extract a list of top 10 products(based on count) for each subcategory( a combo of seller,catgid,subcatgid) and want a result like :

Seller1, catg1,subcatg1,{{prodid1,prod1details},{prodid2,prod2details},{prodid3,prod3details},{prodid4,prod4details}....}

Seller2, catg2,subcatg2,{{prodid5,prod5details},{prodid6,prod6details},{prodid7,prod7details},{prodid8,prod8details}....}

So basically I want the product details(preferably in json format) for all the top 10 products till each subcategory 
level.
Is this even possible with a hive query? If yes, then could you please provide an example and If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the above question at http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/extract-top-n-records-in-each-group-in-hadoophive/

Answer (score 0):

Mohit,
  Take a look at the 'collect_max' UDF in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) . I think it can provide a more scalable solution for larger datasets ( in that you can reduce the amount of sorting that you need to do).

Comment: What I need to do is to run a query on log data for top 10 products(count wise) in  each sub category. What adds a bit more complexity is that I need all the information of the product. Now when I do group by with only subcatg,pid, I can only select the same fields. But I want all the data for that product coming in the same row as subcatg & prodid like prodname, proddesc,price, mrp,imageurl. And since some information like price & proddesc of a product keep on changing I want to pick the latest column values(according to a date field) for a pid if we are able to do a group by on subcatg,pid.